# Nice way in React to Map an array data to Card Decks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects. And I can't figure out how do I create multiple card decks with 3 cards in each one, as on the image:
[image]

An example is below:

```
import { Card, Button, ... CardBlock } from 'reactstrap';

export default const Example = (props) => {
  return (<div>
    <CardDeck>
      <Card>
        <CardImg top width="100%" src="https://..." />
        <CardBlock>
          <CardTitle>{data.title}</CardTitle>
          <CardSubtitle>{data.subtitle}/CardSubtitle>
          <CardText>{data.text}</CardText>
          <Button>Button</Button>
        </CardBlock>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        ...
      </Card>
      <Card>
        ...
      </Card>
    </CardDeck>

    <CardDeck>
       ... 
    </CardDeck> 
       ...
  </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: So what doesn't work as expected in your code? Can you ask a specific question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is about how to iterate over your array then you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for it.

An example from the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#embedding-map-in-jsx) with `map()` call using an arrow function:

By saving the components in a temporary variable:

```
function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <ListItem key={number.toString()}
              value={number} />
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

By using `map()` inline:

```
function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  return (
    <ul>
      {numbers.map((number) =>
        <ListItem key={number.toString()}
                  value={number} />
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

**EDIT:**

Do not render multiple `<CardDeck>` components. Instead adapt your css so that a `<Card>` will wrap into the next row when there are more that three. Then you only have to map the data inside your array once and not for every `<CardDeck>` again.

Comment: You propose me to do <CardDeck> items.map(...) </CardDeck><CardDeck> items.map(...) </CardDeck><CardDeck> items.map(...) </CardDeck>? What if my array.length is 30 items => then I have to create 10 maps?

Comment: Well i don't propose anything. You didn't ask a question so i did guess what exactly it is that you struggle with. If your datastrucure is an array, than you should adapt your css, so that a fourth card will float in the next row and only iterate over your structure once. You should design a component, so that it can render an arbitrary amount of cards and not that kind of a fixed layout with always 6 or 9 or whatever amount.

Comment: Well react is a frontend rendering framework not a grid system. You can use somethink like flexbox or bootstrap or another css framework to make things easier so that you do not have to start from the ground. Then you can use that inside your react components. If you want 3 boxes each row then make each box 33% width an let the boxes float. This way it will work with arbitrary amounts.

Comment: @Taras Yaremkiv why did you downvote (If you where the one)? Stackoverflow is not there to do your job and provide you with fully working code snippets. I gave you the hints that you need. Since you did not ask any question i had to guess, what exactly you are searching for. Normally this question should have been closed. I don't think that it is fair to downvote this. You can leave a coment on what exactly is missing in my answer and i will try and update it. And you can always ask a more precise question when you struggle with anything further down the road.

Comment: The same to you - why did you downvote my question (if you were the one) BTW the answer is far from what I was looking for. In my opinion The answer should be something like - there's no reasonable way to realize this thing unless create multiple Maps, though it doesn't solve the problem  in 100%. Here's an sample of code https://gist.github.com/Y-Taras/83e8a7bab19015ee89db2de0939b4523 you could use but As I said it's a hint.

Comment: @Taras i didn't downvote your question. I actually tried to answer it although those kind of questions normally get closed for being not precise enough. Sorry for being that harsh but you clearly didn't understand the core concepts of rendering dynamical data with languages like `jsx` and css. The way i suggested is exactly the way to go. You only need to map your array once and use css so that your cards wrap into the next line when there are more than three inside it. Also you do not "create" multiple maps but you "map the contents of your array to a function".

Comment: @trixin English is not my native language. And it's not easy for me to be precise, in that case. And I didn't say that  I used this code, it just a variant/option to realize it the way I asked in question yesterday.

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv If you want your component to be able to render an arbitrary amount of cards then your approach will not work. I updated my answer to fit your problem better. Feel free to upvote it if you feel like it's better now. I you aren't precise with your question how do you expect people to be precise with their answers. It's just not fair to downvote instead of commenting what is missing in the answer because i took some time to write it.

Comment: And as a proof i didn't downvote your question i did downvote it now so that it will be -2. I can't downvote twice. I will revert that in 5 minutes so that it will be 0 again. I would apreciate if you do the same.

Comment: ))  You do not have to prove it. I believed it at once. I guess this discussion isn't worth our time because I still haven't done the assignment so I need to keep working on it